# ModalPopupExtender Show() not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I am aware that this question has been asked many times over the internet. However, even after reading and trying all those solutions, I still cannot find a right solution. I am hoping someone could help me out of this issue.

My code is based on  [this guy's code](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/modalpopupextender_example_for.html).

I have a GridView that sources its data from the SqlDataSource1. Within that GridView, in the first column I have View buttons that should show the details of each row in the ModalPopupExtender1. I set its TargetControlID to btnShowPopup, which is not visible but as I say "not visible" doesn't mean it's set Visible="false" but it is set style="display:none" (I found this is the way people do).

The problem is even when I click on one of the View buttons, the ModalPopup doesn't appear. In fact, when I click the button, nothing happens.

On the Visual Basic, I don't see any error messages nor exception handlers after clicking on the View button.

This issue has been bugging me in the past couple of days.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code.
aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SearchAcquisition.aspx.cs" Inherits="PosStock" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="headContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Maincontent" Runat="Server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="contentboxh">
    <h2 class="hpos">Acquisition Search</h2>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h2 class="h4" style="text-align: left">Search</h2>
        <br />

        <asp:TextBox ID="SearchField" runat="server" Width="350px" Height="30px" OnTextChanged="SearchField_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" Height="26px" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" BackColor="#7AB800" CssClass="searchbutton" />

    </div>
    <div class="contentboxh">

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT [acquisition_ID], [acquisition_name], [acquisition_qty], [acquisition_cost], [acquisition_date], [acquisition_status] FROM [Acquisition] WHERE [acquisition_ID] = @acquisition_ID"
            SelectCommandType="Text" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="true" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MJENTAConnectionString %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="acquisition_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10" Width="95%">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="50px" HeaderStyle-Width="60px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnViewDetails" runat="server" Text="Details" CommandName="View" OnClick="BtnViewDetails_Click" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="acquisition_ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="acquisition_ID" ReadOnly="true" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="acquisition_name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="acquisition_name" ReadOnly="true" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="acquisition_qty" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="acquisition_qty" ReadOnly="true" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="acquisition_cost" HeaderText="Cost" SortExpression="acquisition_cost" ReadOnly="true" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="acquisition_date" HeaderText="Date Added" SortExpression="acquisition_date" ReadOnly="true" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="acquisition_status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="acquisition_status" ReadOnly="true" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


        <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" />
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlPopup"
                        CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="detail" Width="500px" style="display:none">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlCustomerDetail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerDetail" runat="server" Text="Detail" BackColor="LightBlue" Width="95%" />
                    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Edit" Width="95%" BackColor="White" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <div align="right" style="width:95%">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="50px" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" Width="50px" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class PosStock : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void BtnViewDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnDetails = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btnDetails.NamingContainer;

        this.SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();
        this.SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("acquisition_ID", Convert.ToString(this.GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value));
        this.DetailsView1.DataSource = this.SqlDataSource1;
        this.DetailsView1.DataBind();

        this.updPnlCustomerDetail.Update();
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

    }
    protected void SearchField_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new     SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MJENTAConnectionString"].ToString());

        SqlCommand cmd;

        String str = "SELECT acquisition_ID, acquisition_name, acquisition_qty, acquisition_cost, acquisition_date, acquisition_status FROM Acquisition WHERE (acquisition_name like '%' + @search + '%')";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = SearchField.Text;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "acquisition_name");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```